# Animate along a path while path is parented to camera rotation

Tags: animation, parent, path

I'm creating a short anim loop of the trench run in Star Wars. I have the camera keframed with some rotation and location data (position in the cockpit chasing rebel X-Wing)
I want to shoot the lasers and had an idea to use a follow path instruction where the Path is parented to the camera.
But it seems I cant keyframe when the path should start.(for example, shoot lasers on frame 18-22)
When I try I get this message.[image]

It seems like there is a clash between the Location/Rotation data from the camera and the path following data. Is there a way to get these to work together or even a better way of achieving what I want?

Thanks

Comment: OK I've found out that the particle system is a better way to achieve this. I have some problems with that too but I'll start another thread for that issue. Thanks

Comment: You don't want to animate a path follow that way anyway.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261415/42221) for how to use the curve's evaluation time instead.  But using the approach from that answer you can definitely do the relevant animation directly.