# Turntable animation with variable speeds

Tags: animation, camera

trying to get my camera to whip around a subject on a turntable, slow down, then ramp back up again.

Im using a Follow path constraint on a circle, i can only get either a continuous loop or it comes to a complete stop before looping again when I try to control the speed.

Here's an example of type of shots Im trying to go for.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AkModwf40w

There's even a breakdown of the specific shot (Starts at 31:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOFQG095fYI&t=1872s

If you'll notice the camera slows down but doesn't come to a complete stop before starting again.

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/HsOSDYTsG7o) video on changing the animation speed on a path helps. There's also this answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261354/camera-path-animation-speed-change?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but these only work for paths that are not looping. I need control over speed at a specific point while maintaining a smooth loop.

Comment: Ok. Why not use an Empty rather than a path in that case and try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1pAn1df-yQ) tutorial. You can change the speed by key framing the angle at various positions along the timeline.